# Trigger Keydown on input with JavaScript function (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

How can I simulate a keypress of the "right arrow" key to an input, using vanilla javascript?

I have an input and a button. I want the button to trigger a keydown for the "right arrow" key on the input.

```
 <input id="myInput" type="text">
 <button id="myButton>Click Me</button>
```

Basically, the end result should be :

1. Click the button
2. Cursor moves one place to the right (because
   we triggered a keydown press)

I have tried these solutions but they don't work:

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

https://elgervanboxtel.nl/site/blog/simulate-keydown-event-with-javascript

Comment: See this page for a working example of what you need to do. https://snipplr.com/view/5144/getset-cursor-in-html-textarea/

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right

Comment: If you click a button and initiate a right arrow key event, why do you expect the cursor move in some unrelated text input field as a result? Focus would be on the button element, so a key down on that element would probably attempt to scroll the page right (or something like that). If you're trying to initiate a key event, your links show you how to do that, but I wouldn't expect that to solve your cusor positioning problem straight away. If you're trying to move a cursor in a text box by button click, the key event isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [handy blog post](http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/) that gives you the full scoop on positioning a cursor in a text area. Here's a proof-of-concept version that may not work for older browsers (see link for a compatible version):

```js
let cursorLocation = 0;

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", e => {
  var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(++cursorLocation, cursorLocation);
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="sample text">
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```